# Differentiation of integral $\int \limits_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}dt$

Tags: calculus

Let $h$ be the function defined by $h(x)=\int \limits_{0}^{x^2}e^{x+t}dt$ for all real numbers $x$. Evaluate $h'(1)$.

**My solution:**  The fundamental theorem of calculus $h'(x)=e^{x+x^2}\cdot (x^2)'=2xe^{x+x^2}$. Setting $x=1$ we get $h(1)=2e^2$. However my answer is incorrect.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The integrand also contains a function depending on $x$.

$$h(x)=\exp(x)\int_{t=0}^{x^2}\exp(t)dt$$

Now use the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus (which is an overkill in this case :D).

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{x+t}\mbox{d}t=e^{x+t}\Big|_{t=0}^{x^2}=e^{x+x^2}-e^x.$$
$$h'(x)=e^{x+x^2}(1+2x)-e^x.$$
$$h'(1)=3e^2-e.$$